# Approach for setting up a memcahed cluster

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I have a 3 server Hadoop cluster ,I also want to set up a memcached cluster on these three machines  , as the memcached instance is not aware of the other instances, do I have to use a load balancing technology like LVS.

If so then if I have to make the cluster highly available then I need to populate the data that needs to subsequently fetched from all the memcahed servers using their individual IPs at application start up so that the data is replicated across all three nodes .Is this the right approach?

In short use LVS for all the gets from Memcahed "cluster" and use individual IPs of all the memcahed nodes at the start up time to put the data , this is ofcourse assuming that my memcahed data is not going to change over the lifetime of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not scalable and thus not suited for a distributed cluster design. You don't want your cached data to be replicated to each and every cluster memeber as it prevents you from leveraging the benefit of a split-up working set -- which is most likely the reason why you cluster. 
The reason for that is if you use some kind of reverse proxy/ load balancer like LVS, every member of the memcache cluster can get requests from every hadoop member and thus in steady state, every memcache server has the same data cached.
I would let each cluster use its local memcache istance with just connecting to local host. This way data locality and the shared working set is maintained.

Comment: I am sorry ,I am not clear if you are suggesting that the data should be split up or not?

Comment: Yes, that's what I propose

Comment: I am always , happy , but the answer is not clear , you begin with saying that you dont want your data to be replicated and then go on to say that every memcached server has same data cached ... I am lost.